# EWS API Java : the request failed. null

Tags: java, web-services, api, exchangewebservices

When I call the EWS Java API from a web service, I get an error.
The full stacktrace is below.
FYI, `com.ixbat.synchroexchangews` is our web service. It calls a JAR (synchroexchange.*), which calls the EWS API.

Is the EWS API able to be called from another web service?
Why this error is occurring?

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. null
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:74)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.MultiResponseServiceRequest.execute(MultiResponseServiceRequest.java:158)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.internalCreateItems(ExchangeService.java:598)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.createItem(ExchangeService.java:657)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.internalCreate(Item.java:245)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item.save(Item.java:386)
at synchroexchange.ExtendedTask.create(ExtendedTask.java:108)
at synchroexchange.ExchangeManager.wsPropagerAction(ExchangeManager.java:734)
at synchroexchange.ExchangeManager.wsPropagerAction(ExchangeManager.java:702)
at com.ixbat.synchroexchangews.SynchroExchangews.propagerAction(SynchroExchangews.java:152)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:117)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:199)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:640)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:284)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:293)
at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:137)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:120)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:217)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:81)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:220)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3436)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.writeCharacters(BaseStreamWriter.java:451)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.EwsServiceXmlWriter.writeValue(EwsServiceXmlWriter.java:307)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.StringList.writeElementsToXml(StringList.java:117)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.ComplexProperty.writeToXml(ComplexProperty.java:325)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.ComplexProperty.writeToXml(ComplexProperty.java:338)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.definition.ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.writePropertyValueToXml(ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.java:170)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.PropertyBag.writeToXml(PropertyBag.java:548)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.ServiceObject.writeToXml(ServiceObject.java:321)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.CreateRequest.writeElementsToXml(CreateRequest.java:129)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.writeBodyToXml(ServiceRequestBase.java:134)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.writeToXml(ServiceRequestBase.java:256)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.buildEwsHttpWebRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:696)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.buildEwsHttpWebRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:665)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.ServiceRequestBase.validateAndEmitRequest(ServiceRequestBase.java:635)
at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.request.SimpleServiceRequestBase.internalExecute(SimpleServiceRequestBase.java:62)
... 63 more
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Do you just want to know the cause of your stack trace or something else? Please see the SO guidelines for asking questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, i would like to know why there is this error. I edit the main post.

Comment: Cool. Since you edited the post, I have removed the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual code, I can't be sure, but I would surmise based on your stack trace that you are sending a request to a web service, but when it is marshaling the XML one of the fields is null, and so it is throwing this exception. I would encourage you to debug and figure out if any fields you are trying to send are in fact, missing.

Comment: In fact, the bug is from the line 74 : https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/core/request/SimpleServiceRequestBase.java. It's strange because it works well when i call the same method create "normally". But when i call it from another web-service, it doesn't work. Any idea if a web-service can call another web-service ?

Comment: I suspect that what's happening is that in the context where you call the method "normally", this web service is actually running some internal setup code that puts itself into a correct state which is leveraged to call the downstream service. However, when you call from another web service, the intermediate web service doesn't put itself into the correct state and run the necessary preliminary code. The only thing I can say is debug both paths to figure out what is going on, which may take a while. :-/

Comment: As for your question, absolutely! One of the key benefits of web services is that they act like functions in that they can call each other as needed.